# How can make notepad++ be my default opener?

Tags: notepad++

I installed notepad++ in D drive. When I try to open a text with *Open with...* and browse the notepad++ to be my default program it isn't chosen. What should I do to make my default opener?

Comment: What is the [tag:os]?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nifty little youtube video that explains how to do just that.

[Set Notepad++ to default editor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g63OHRS3aos)

Edit: Specifically in regards to markdown it looks like this has been covered before:
[How to use markdown in notpad++](https://www.gazelle.com/iphone/iphone-5s/other/iphone-5s-64gb-other/495471-gpid)

Comment: Thanks for your help. but when I choose notepad++ it doesn't appear to the window so I can't choose it. Could it be possible because of being located in D drive? Should  re-install it in C drive?

Comment: That was my next thought, try installing on the C drive instead.  Let me know how that works.

Comment: I checked more reference as use mentioned and it helped me in .txt, .htm, ... files. I was great. But unfortunately I wanted to open .md files by default with notepad++ that it's not in the formats. Is there other way?

Comment: [take a look at this](http://allthingsmarked.com/2009/07/29/associate-file-extensions-with-specific-languages-in-notepad-plus-plus/)

Comment: [heres another super user thread that might be helpful](http://superuser.com/questions/586177/how-to-use-markdown-in-notepad)

Comment: Wow thanks. The one to the last really helped me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey glad to hear it! If you feel like i answered the question I'd appreciate it if you answered it and/or upvoted it.  Thanks, glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
Did you have previous 32bit version? and installed 64bit.
Anyway, try to find this in Registry
- open "Run" or press "Windows + R"
- type "regedit"
- Click "Edit" -> "Find"
- Search for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
- make sure that path exist. If not, replace it with correct path
Most probably you have an issue with windows registry.
```